# Magento 2 : Issue with line item price in shipment email

Tags: magento2

Vendor/Sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_shipment_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Shipment Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="items">
            <action method="setTemplate" >
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Sales::email/shipment/items.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page
```

> 

Vendor/Sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/shipment/default.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item         = $block->getItem();
$_order        = $_item->getOrder();
$helper        = $this->helper('Vendor\Sales\Helper\Data');
$product_image = $helper->getProductImage($_item->getSku());
$productObj    = $helper->getProductBySku($_item->getSku());
$color         = $productObj->getAttributeText('color');
$size          = $productObj->getAttributeText('size');
$brand         = $productObj->getDisplayBrand();
$product_url = $helper->getProductFrontendUrl($productObj);
$itemDiscounted = false;
$itemFree = false;
$itemQty       = $_item->getQty();
$specialPrice = $helper->formatProductPrice($_order->getOrderCurrencyCode(),$productObj->getSpecialPrice());
$regular_price = $helper->formatProductPrice($_order->getOrderCurrencyCode(),$productObj->getPrice('regular_price'));
$originalPrice = $_item->getOriginalPrice() > 0 ? $_item->getOriginalPrice() : $regular_price;

$store = $block->getOrder()->getStore()->getCode();
$itemRowTotal = $store == 'us' ? $_item->getPrice() * $itemQty : $_item->getPriceInclTax() * $itemQty;
```

$itemRowTotal is set as product price in shipment email
but it shows 0 instead of actual price

any thoughts what can be the issue ?

Comment: I found that on some product/time this $_item->getPriceInclTax() method is not found on $_item object.

Comment: any thoughts what can be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xdebug or set a log to check the data of the $_item variable. I think this variable is not having data